# How to create an object from a subclass in Java

Tags: java

So I have this class:

```
public class parent {
     private int id;
     private int row;
     public parent(int id,int row) {
        this.id=id;
        this.row=row
     }
}
```

and then I have this class which extends parent

```
public class son extends parent {
    public son(int id,int row) {
        super(id,son);
    }
}
```

the question is how do i create an object for class son.Do I have to call it like this:

```
son x=new son(int id,int row);
```

I am really confused.

Comment: Yes, you can call it that way.. Or you can use the parent's reference to refer to the son class's instance

Comment: I really don't like the lower case class naming.

Comment: Leave out the types, but otherwise your syntax should work. son x=new son(id, row);

Comment: What if I give a certain id and row to parent and want to create a son object keiping this variables at the same amount?The only way is to call its constructor with these vairiables as inputs?

Comment: @Jenny - Yes, that's the right way. And you are already doing it :)

Comment: @JasonZ Agree with you, reminds me of some college teachers who  don't even bother on naming conventions and indentations. Simply speechless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, you're just about spot on! To be absolutely clear, you wouldn't use the type of `id` and `row` in calling the constructor, you would just give values of that type.

So this is wrong:

```
son x = new son(int 5, int 6); //Incorrect
```

And this is correct:

```
son x = new son(5, 6); //Correct
```

You can also pass variables of the correct type, like this:

```
int id = 5;
int row = 6;
son x = new son(id, row);
```

Also, I just noticed that you wrote:

```
public class parent {
     private int id;
     private id row;
     //....
```

instead of

```
public class parent {
     private int id;
     private int row;  //Note the change id --> int here
     //....
```

If this was a typo, don't worry about it. Otherwise you may have a conceptual misunderstanding. `id` isn't a type, but `int` is. So we can't declare `row` as an `id`, but we can declare it as an `int`. Unlike in `C` and friends you can't create synonyms of types with a `typedef`, so you're stuck with the base types (`int`, `boolean`, etc).

---

Since it appears that you're new to Java, the convention is for classes to have Pronoun Case (capitalized first letter of each word) names. Thus it would be better style to use the following formatting for your classes:

```
public class Parent {
     private int id;
     private int row;
     public Parent(int id,int row) {
        this.id=id;
        this.row=row
     }
}

public class Son extends Parent {
    public Son(int id,int row) {
        super(id,son);
    }
}

public class ThisClassHasManyWordsInItAndItShouldBeFormattedLikeThis {
   //.....
}
```

Which then makes the construction:

```
Son x = new Son(5,6);
```

---

Once you've constructed a `Parent` object like `Parent p = new Parent(4,5);`, there's no way to change `p` into a `Son`. It's not possible. *However*, you can copy `p` into a new `Son`, and you can make some modifications to the classes to make it easier to make these copies:

```
public class Parent {
     private int id;
     private int row;
     public Parent(int id,int row) {
        this.id=id;
        this.row=row
     }

     public int getId() {
         return id;
     }

     public int getRow() {
         return row;
     }
}

public class Son extends Parent {
    public Son(int id,int row) {
        super(id,son);
    }

    public Son(Parent p) {
        super(p.getId(), p.getRow());
    }
}
```

Now we can create a Parent, and *copy* it into a new Son:

```
Parent p = new Parent(4,5);
Son s = new Son(p);  //will have id of 4 and row of 5
```

---

It's worth noting that while all this is well and good for learning how class extension works, you're not actually using it quite correctly. By saying `Son extends Parent`, you're saying that `Son` *is a type of* `Parent`, which isn't true in the elementary school model of a Family. A better way to model a family would probably be:

```
public class Person {
    private Person mother;
    private Person father;

    public Person(Person mother, Person father) {
        this.mother = mother;
        this.father = father;
    }
 }
```

If you're still looking for a way to include class extension, then `Man` and `Woman` make sense as extensions of class `Person`, because a `Man` *is a type of* `Person`. (i.e. All men are people, not all people are men).

```
public class Person {
    private Man father;
    private Woman mother;

    public Person(Man father, Woman mother) {
        this.father = father;
        this.mother = mother;
    }
}

public class Man extends Person {
    public Man(Man father, Woman mother) {
        super(father, mother);
    }
}

public class Woman extends Person {
    public Woman(Man father, Woman mother) {
        super(father, mother);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I am pretty new to Java.Thank you for the aswer but lets assume an other scenario.I create a Parent object
   
        Parent  x = new Parent(5,6);

how do I create an object from Son keeping the same variables as input?Isn't there a way to make this object without having to put in these variables?

Comment: Aha! No, not directly. But you can make there be one. I'll edit my answer now.

Comment: Yes that was what I meant to do from the beggining!Thank you